# white space between 2 borders

Tags: html, css

Is this fixable?

https://gyazo.com/9716e632d85339c13bc04920d901d8c8

If you zoom into the image you can see white space between the outside div border and the inside div background-color.

```
<div class="box">
 <div class="box-inner"></div>
</div>
```

```
.box {
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
.box-inner {
 border: 2px solid red;
 background-color: red;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: you have a red background so why adding a red border? you simply but the black one there

Comment: I couldnt understand that in your code there is no white borders. There are black and red.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem appears becasue inner border radius is deferent from child outer border radius.

According to [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#corner-shaping) the `inner-radius = outer-radius - border-width` as was metiond by @Zohir Salak, the border radius of child element should be equals to inner border radous of parent element.

```css
.box {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.box-inner {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: calc(10px - 2px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Another aproach is to remove `border-radius` and `border` from `.box-inner`,
and add `overflow: hidden;` to `.box` element. This way child corners will overlap over parent rounded borders, we fix it by using `overflow: hidden` to trim the corners of child elemtn.

```css
.box {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box-inner {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Also such problem could be fixed be removing background color from `.box-inner` and adding it to `.box`. Where background of an element is a total size of content, padding and border. Find more on [w3.org colors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html)

```css
.box {
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: red;
}
.box-inner {
  //other css
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 <div class="box-inner">some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should explain *why* adding `overflow:hidden;` is needed and solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First Demo of the issue

```css
.box {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50px;
}

.box-inner {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}

body {
  zoom: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inner"></div>
</div>
```

---

The issue is simple, When we define a radius it shapes the corner from the outside `outer radius` as well as the inside `inner radius`, inside is refereed to as `padding edger radius` *(padding comes before border duh)*.

Your inner element's border radius didn't match the curve because you didn't respect the formula for the `inner radius`.

The formula for the `inner radius` is as follows:

```
Outer radius - border width = inner radius
```

In your case:

```
10px - 2px = 8px
```

**Solution**

Now we apply the math

```css
.box {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50px;
}

.box-inner {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inner"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Examples**

Using css variables to do the math dynamically

```css
.box {
  border: var(--borderWidth) solid black;
  border-radius: var(--borderRaduis);
  width: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.box-inner {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: calc(var(--borderRaduis) - var(--borderWidth));
  height: 50px;
}

body {
  zoom: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--borderWidth:2px;--borderRaduis:10px">
  <div class="box-inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="--borderWidth:6px;--borderRaduis:15px">
  <div class="box-inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="--borderWidth:10px;--borderRaduis:15px">
  <div class="box-inner"></div>
</div>

<p> If the calculation result is negative, the inner radius fallsback to 0 </p>
<div class="box" style="--borderWidth:10px;--borderRaduis:6px">
  <div class="box-inner"></div>
</div>
```

**Reference : https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#corner-shaping**

Answer (score 0):

This css should work for you.

```
.box {
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 12px;
//  width:50px; 
}
.box-inner {
/*  border: 2px solid red; */
 background-color: red;
 border-radius: 10px;
//  height: 50px;
//  width:50px;
}
```

Tip: Always attach codepen or some other online editor link.

Comment: Stack Overflow supplies "stack snippets". No need to use any third party site. And using a third party site might get your question or answer closed.